# Evaluating combination with vectorized function in Julia

Tags: julia

In Julia, vectorized function with dot `.` is used for element-wise manipulation.

Running `f.(x)` means `f(x[1])`, `f(x[2])`,... are sequentially executed

However, suppose I have a function which takes two arguments, say `g(x,y)`

I want `g(x[1],y[1])`,`g(x[2],y[1])`, `g(x[3],y[1])`, ..., `g(x[1],y[2])`, `g(x[2],y[2])`, `g(x[3],y[2])`, ...

Is there any way to evaluate all combination of `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matt's answer is good, but I'd like to provide an alternative using an array comprehension:

```
julia> x = 1:5
       y = 10:10:50
       [i + j for i in x, j in y]
5×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 11  21  31  41  51
 12  22  32  42  52
 13  23  33  43  53
 14  24  34  44  54
 15  25  35  45  55
```

In my opinion the array comprehension can often be more readable and more flexible than `broadcast` and `reshape`.

Comment: Thanks!! In terms of readability, this looks better while both are nice

Answer (score 5):

Yes, reshape `y` such that it is orthogonal to `x`.  The `.` vectorization uses [`broadcast`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/arrays#Base.broadcast) to do its work. I imagine this as "extruding" singleton dimensions across all the other dimensions.

That means that for vectors `x` and `y`, you can evaluate the product of all combinations of `x` and `y` simply by reshaping one of them:

```
julia> x = 1:5
       y = 10:10:50
       (+).(x, reshape(y, 1, length(y)))
5×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 11  21  31  41  51
 12  22  32  42  52
 13  23  33  43  53
 14  24  34  44  54
 15  25  35  45  55
```

Note that the shape of the array matches the orientation of the arguments; `x` spans the rows and `y` spans the columns since it was transposed to a single-row matrix.

Comment: Should also note that `reshape` creates a view, and thus doesn't make a temporary array. So there's no worries about performance when doing this.

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer this over `func(x, y.')`, or in this case `x .+ y.'`? Transpose also creates a view. **Edit:** Oops, it only does on version 0.6, on 0.5 you must use reshape, though in this case the memory use shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yes. Right now, transpose and ctranspose don't work for arrays of non-numeric elements. It's looking like that may change, thankfully.